# Preposition used for curtains

Tags: grammar, prepositions, british-english

is ''the curtains are ***on*** the window'' correct in British English?

The preposition ''by'' sounds weird to me when talking about curtains. I'd say '' in front of'' or ''next to''.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I certainly would never say that, but I'd know what someone else meant when they said it. I'd probably say "in the window", or "hung in the window". All that is as a native speaker of British English.